# How to open link outside of iframe that opens iframe source into new window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

```
<a href="//source of iframe name blah//" target="about:blank">open in new window</a>

<a href="1.html" target="blah">link 1</a>
<a href="2.html" target="blah">link 2</a>
<a href="3.html" target="blah">link 3</a>

<iframe name="blah" src="blah.html" ></iframe>
```

I have a page with an iframe in it. I have links that open pages inside the iframe, so the iframe doesn't have just one constant source. I want there to be a link that will open whatever source is currently in the iframe into a new window, whether it be 1.html, 2.html, or 3.html, etc (more pages will constantly be added so there won't just be three in the future).

How would I implement this link? Thank you so much in advance! :~)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $('a[target="blah"]').on('click',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       window.open(this.href,'blah');
    });
});
```